# Problem wth SvcUtil.exe command

Tags: wcf, web-services, visual-studio-2010

I am attempting to generate a proxy using the SvcUtil.exe tool in VS2010 Tools, I am using the following command

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\SvcUtil.exe /language:cs 
   /out:generatedProxy.cs /config:app.config http://localhost:8000/Service"
```

When I enter this comman in the directory of the client I am attempting generate the proxy for, I  get the following error from the comman tool.

```
The filename,directory of volumn label syntax is incorrect
```

I am not quite sure why it is telling me this.

Is there anything obvious that I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should close the quotes after svcutil.exe, instead of at the end of the line - the command prompt is not finding a program with that name in your line.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\SvcUtil.exe"
    /language:cs /out:generatedProxy.cs
    /config:app.config http://localhost:8000/Service
```

Comment: Awesome! This took care of it, I need to work on my command line skills apparently =)